# Цикл For Python

Tags: python, for

Мне нужно получить что-то вроде этого:

```
[{
«name»: «Tulip Serenade»,
«days»: 8,
«itinerary»: [amsterdam,amsterdam,arnhem …..],
«dates»:[
{«2019-04-04»:{«ship»: «ms amadeus queen», «price»:1044.65},
...(остальные даты)}
],
},..]
```

С `name`, `days` and `itinerary` все в порядке, но что делать с `dates`? У меня есть **3 списка**: `date`, `ship` и `price`.

Я пытаюсь сделать так:

```
for a, b, c in zip(date, ship, price):
     dates = [{a: {'ship': b, 'price': c}}]


data = [{'name': name,
        'days': days,
        'itinerary': itinerary,
        'dates': dates
        }]
```

Но получаю:

```
[[{'name': 'Tulip Serenade', 'days': ' 8', 'itinerary': [' Amsterdam ', ' Amsterdam ', ' Arnhem ', ' Middelburg ', ' Ghent ', ' Antwerp ', ' Rotterdam ', ' Amsterdam '], 'dates': [{'26. Apr 2021 - 03. May 2021': {'ship': 'MS Amadeus Silver III', 'price': ' € 1.619,00 '}}]}]
```

Вместо нескольких `dates`, несмотря на то, что там есть данные!

Что мне делать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Наверно, должно быть так:

```
dates = []
for a, b, c in zip(date, ship, price):
     dates.append({a: {'ship': b, 'price': c}})
```